# two grammar mistakes: (since/as of/starting) and combination of (under renovation) and (since/as of/starting)

Tags: word-usage

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) The supermarket has been **under renovation** **since** two months **ago**.

(2) The supermarket has been **under renovation** **as of** two months **ago**.

(3) The supermarket has been **under renovation** **starting** two months **ago**.

My non-native English speaking friends think there are two mistakes. They think the combination of "under renovation" and "... ago" sounds odd. The second mistake they have found is that it's ungrammatical to say "since/as of/starting.... ago".

Do you agree with my friends on the two mistakes?

Comment: None of them are colloquial. "under renovation" seems to need either a 'date' ("since Monday", "since January"), or "for" followed by a period of time. We would probably say, "The supermarket has been under renovation for two months" or "They started renovating the supermarket two months ago".

Comment: "As of" is discussed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112770/understanding-as-of-as-at-and-as-from. It sounds slightly officious compared with "since".